# MERN app - how does someone run it locally with a database connection

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, github, deployment

So I have 2 assignments for different job applications. I can deploy on Heroku by using the free Cluster in Mongodb Atlas, but how would they get the second application to work on their computer? I want it to be as easily done as possible for them, but it seems that they will need to download Node.js and MongoDB compass to their computer.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using a PaaS?
If you build the app only for the purpose of the interview then it means the webapp should be "accessible/live" only for a few hours at max while it's being reviewed.
The major cloud providers have some free tiers which should help host your app for the interview for free.

(for DB MongoDB Atlas should be good enough)

There are many articles on that since the cloud is very popular nowadays.

Services like: Azure Web Apps, Azzure App Service, Google App Engine and so on should work.

Comment: That's the issue, I'm already using my free Atlas cluster, 2 clusters running at the same time would cost